# Is it possible to put several objects together inside a union?

Tags: c++, unions

What if I have this:

```
union{
    vector<int> intVec ;
    vector<float> floatVec ;
    vector<double> doubleVec ;
} ;
```

Of course, I'll be using just one of the 3 vectors. But... what happens when all the 3 vectors are contructed??
Would the consructors of the 3 vectors interfere with each other?? (since the 3 of them are in the same memory address)

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Current C++ standard does not allow non-POD types inside unions. You will get this compiler error from `gcc`:

```
error: member ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >
<anonymous union>::i’ with constructor not allowed in union
error: member ‘std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >
<anonymous union>::i’ with destructor not allowed in union
```

New C++ standard ([C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x)) proposes [unrestricted unions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Unrestricted_unions), but it [adds yet *more* object lifetime pitfalls to C++](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=407).

Answer (score 9):

You cannot have unions containing non-POD class types. Your sample will not compile.

You can use `boost::variant` as a safe alternative to C unions. See the [documentation on boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/variant.html). You might, however, reconsider your design and use polymorphism instead. Depends on what you're trying to accomplish, of course.

Comment: Yes, I know Boost::variant and Boost:any. I just wanted to be sure if this would be possible or not before considering a different approach.  
Thanks.

Comment: You can have unions containing class types, but they must be POD. see Checkers' answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the C++ Standard, section 9.5:

> An object of a class with a
>   non-trivial constructor (12.1), a
>   non-trivial copy constructor (12.8), a
>   non-trivial destructor (12.4), or a
>   non-trivial copy assignment operator
>   (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a member of a
>   union,

Here, for "non-trivial" read "useful" :-)

Comment: Even more than that, trivial implies implicitly defined. If the constructor is defined in code, it is inherently non-trivial.

Answer (score 2):

> Would the consructors of the 3 vectors interfere with each other?? (since the 3 of them are in the same memory address)

The C++ standard doesn't allow your program, so it's (at best!) implementation-defined what happens.

If, say, your implementation invokes all three default contructors, and those all alocate memory, and stores the pointer to the newly allocated space, the you have a memory leak (the first Two allocations are overwritten by the third).

If the destructors are all invoked and they all free "their" memory, you will be doing a double free (triple, acually); this is likely to corrupt the allocation data structure, which is a Bad Thing.  Be happy if you crash, because it's much harder to debug if you don't.

I think these problems might be *why* the standard doesn't allow this.

(A more sensical thing might be to only default-construct the first class, but that's still not sensical, just less insane...)

Answer (score 2):

Now C++ standard supports variant. Check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant.

`std::variant`

Defined in header

```cpp
template <class... Types>   
class variant;
```

<sup>(since C++17)</sup>

The class template `std::variant` represents a type-safe [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union). An instance of `std::variant` at any given time either holds a value of one of its alternative types, or in the case of error - no value (this state is hard to achieve, see [valueless_by_exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/valueless_by_exception)).

As with unions, if a variant holds a value of some object type T, the object representation of T is allocated directly within the object representation of the variant itself. Variant is not allowed to allocate additional (dynamic) memory.

A variant is not permitted to hold references, arrays, or the type void. Empty variants are also ill-formed (`std::variant<std::monostate>` can be used instead).

A variant is permitted to hold the same type more than once, and to hold differently cv-qualified versions of the same type.

Consistent with the behavior of unions during [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), a default-constructed variant holds a value of its first alternative, unless that alternative is not default-constructible (in which case the variant is not default-constructible either). The helper class [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) can be used to make such variants default-constructible.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/variant.html) which can contain a single value of varying types.